# PUT request from RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm looking to send a PUT command to a server from R. The following unix commandline snippet works fine:

```
curl -i -k -u "username:pass" -X PUT -d "description=test+test+test" https://somewebsite.com/application
```

I've tried various iterations on httpPUT(), and I'm now working with the inner function getURLContent:

```
curl_opts = curlOptions(username = "username", password = "pass", httpauth=AUTH_BASIC,     ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, headerfunction=h$update)

url=paste("https://somewebsite.com/", "application", sep="")

info <- "description=test+test+test"
val <- charToRaw(info)  
getURLContent(url, infilesize = length(val), readfunction = val, upload = TRUE, customrequest = "PUT", .opts=curl_opts)
```

The server is sending back a search like response, as if I did not actually post the data.  Any thoughts on how to recreate the curl commandline PUT in RCurl?

Thanks!

Comment: `httpPUT` (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RCurl/docs/httpPUT) from `RCurl` proper, or `PUT` from the `httr` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf) package (`httr` just wraps `RCurl`)